# How to render SVGs coming from api response using next/image or <img> in Next.js?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, svg, webpack, next.js

I've got a bunch of svgs coming from an api response, which I get inside `useEffect`. Response looks like this

```
{svg1: 'https://remoteserver.com/assests/svg1.svg', ...and so on}
```

( These svgs aren't static coming from `/public` folder. So I don't import them at top.)
I want to render them in nextjs using `next/image` or normal `<img>` tag, passing the url into `src`. I know that next.js by default don't support svgs.

```
 <Image alt='SVG from api'
        src={response.svg1}
        width={'45px'}
        height={'45px'}
        objectFit='contain' />
```

According to [docs](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next/image#dangerously-allow-svg), this is possible with `dangerouslyAllowSVG`, but there is security risk here, so I don't want to go this route.
I know packages like [SVGR](https://react-svgr.com/) and [babel-inline-svg](https://github.com/airbnb/babel-plugin-inline-react-svg) are there to solve the issue, but they are for using svgs as react components.
I've also tried [next-images](https://www.npmjs.com/package/next-images) and made use of `withImages` inside `next.config.js`.

```
const withImages = require('next-images')
module.exports = withImages({
     reactStrictMode: true,
     env: {
        BASE_URL: process.env.BASE_URL
        },
     images: {
      domains: ['remoteserver.com', 'remoteserver2.com']
      },
  webpack(config, options) {
    return config
  }
})
```

But the build is failing when I try `next build`.

```
./static/images/Logo.png
TypeError: unsupported file type: undefined (file: undefined)
```

What am I missing/doing wrong here ? Are there any alternate solutions ?

Comment: If you are in control of SVG content, What is the security risk?

Comment: Well there's a usecase where users can upload svgs and that is being fetched. Although we do have a degree of control over the SVG content, I was just making sure. Also almost none of  the articles online suggested using it.

Comment: The docs also state you can use `contentSecurityPolicy` inside your `next.config.js` to minimise the security vulnerabilities.

Comment: Yeah, I went with this approach. But it wasn't still loading with next/image. So I used a normal <img> tag instead and it worked. Not exactly sure what issue was. Will try to check with next team. So adding that as the answer for now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So apparantly I went with [dangerouslyAllowSVG](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next/image#dangerously-allow-svg) and added the CSP headers.
Still svg wasn't loading with `<Image />` from `next/image`. It worked  when I used normal `<img>` tag though.
Not sure if this is the best fix though :)

Comment: Hi! Did you find a better solution to this, or was sticking to `<img>` tags for external svgs the only viable option that you found? Running into something very similar myself and looking for ideas!